# This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider of your choice?

Tags: flutter

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: _HomePageState#3f040):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this HomePage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: Add more details, we can't help you at this stage